# How to add and make a search box appear within a Picture in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part, search, site-logo

How do i make a Search box(maybe in the form of a searchbox webpart) appear within a Picture(in the form of a picture viewer webpart) on Sharpoint 2010?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your request? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically, i'd like to have an image as the background for a Search Box Web part.

Comment: In SharePoint 2010 you will have to use CSS to do that or roll your own delegate control.

Comment: I used CSS in the v4 of the main site(left area) and it broke other webparts(right area) on the subsites. the subsites are inheriting v4 from the main.

`<style>
      #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ8 table.s4-wpTopTable 
            { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 330px;
      left: 50px;

  }   
    </style>`

Comment: Yep, it's not easy. In 2013/2016 it is easier.